# Parity installation problem in OSX

Tags: clients, mac-osx, installation, parity, rust

During the installation I've got at the end this:

Last 15 lines from /Users/maksim/Library/Logs/Homebrew/parity/02.multirust:

```
 Compiling serde v0.7.4
 Compiling itertools v0.4.13
 Compiling bytes v0.3.0
 Compiling winapi-build v0.1.1
 Compiling bloomchain v0.1.0
 error: linking with `cc` failed: exit code: 1 note: "cc" "-m64" "-L"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/target/release/build/heapsize-40dd75c58e1708a9/build_script_build.0.o"
 "-o"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/target/release/build/heapsize-40dd75c58e1708a9/build_script_build"
 "-Wl,-dead_strip" "-nodefaultlibs" "-L"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/target/release/deps" "-L"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/target/release/deps" "-L"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libstd-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcollections-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librustc_unicode-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/librand-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liballoc_jemalloc-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/liblibc-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "/private/tmp/parity-20160607-9932-1o2o3fo/.brew_home/.multirust/toolchains/stable/lib/rustlib/x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/libcore-d16b8f0e.rlib"
 "-l" "System" "-l" "pthread" "-l" "c" "-l" "m" "-l" "compiler-rt"

 note: ld: entry point (start) undefined.  Usually in crt1.o for architecture x86_64
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

 error: aborting due to previous error
 Build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
 error: Could not compile `heapsize`.

 To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Before I do --verbose, may be someone already can see what the problem is?

Thanks from not so much experienced Mac user!

Update: During installation according to @Ellis get the following:

```
maksims-mbp:parity maksim$ brew update && brew install multirust
Already up-to-date.
Warning: multirust-0.8.0 already installed
maksims-mbp:parity maksim$ multirust default stable
multirust: installing toolchain 'stable'
rustup: gpg not available. signatures will not be verified
rustup: downloading manifest for 'stable'
rustup: command failed: curl -s -f -O https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256
rustup: couldn't download checksum file 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256'
rustup: downloading manifest for 'stable'
rustup: command failed: curl -s -f -O https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.sha256
rustup: couldn't download checksum file 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.sha256'
```

Any ideas on how to fix it? Does it have something to do with "not having 'gpg' "?

Comment: just try: `brew install gpg`

Comment: `multirust: installing toolchain 'stable'
rustup: gpg available. signatures will be verified
rustup: downloading manifest for 'stable'
rustup: command failed: curl -s -f -O https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256
rustup: couldn't download checksum file 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256'
rustup: downloading manifest for 'stable'
rustup: command failed: curl -s -f -O https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.sha256
rustup: couldn't download checksum file 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.sha256'`

Comment: still can't download checksum ?

Comment: just try: brew install curl

Comment: Look in the article about ubuntu. I install many packages: file git curl  bzip2 make

Comment: I'm on Mac not Ubuntu.. Tried `brew install curl`and it was installed. However, the problem from the comment above still exists. I'm getting again `rustup: command failed: curl -s -f -O https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256 rustup: couldn't download checksum file 'https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/channel-rust-stable.toml.sha256'`

Comment: could you check you have curl in your path ? `which curl`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked on parity few weeks ago on OS X. This guide is for Parity 1.2. The build is very long. I suppose you have installed homebrew.

Homebrew (juin 2016) have a preinstalled version of Parity : version 1.1. To avoid any conflict, let's delete this one and jump on 1.2 version :

```
user:~ brew remove parity
```

Ethcore provides a unique command to install Parity, but to install version 1.2, you shouldn't use it, but rather proceed like this :

```
user:~ brew update && brew install multirust
user:~ multirust default stable
user:~ cd && git clone https://github.com/ethcore/parity.git && cd parity
user:~ cargo run --release
user:~ sudo cp parity//target/release/parity /usr/local/bin/
```

This command install the rust compiler and download all that is needed from github. After a few moment, parity is deployed on your system.

If you look for more information, you can read this article:
https://ellis2323.gitbooks.io/blckchn/content/[EN]_Parity.html

Comment: Thanks, @Ellis. During installation have another error, I've updated the initial post.